# How to include <meta charSet="utf-8" /> in react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm using [jest-image-snapshot](https://github.com/americanexpress/jest-image-snapshot) with react-testing-library so that I can run some visual regression tests. The issue I'm having is that I need to define `<meta charSet="UTF-8" />` (otherwise my image-snapshots don't render correctly), however react-testing-library strips out all `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

If I wrap my component like so:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <ComponentToTest />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Then it ends up rendering as:

```
<DocumentFragment>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <ComponentToTest />
</DocumentFragment>
```

Which of course doesn't set the encoding to UTF-8 as it's not within `<head>`.

The result of this is that any components that include a unicode character will render with a weird character instead.

For example, using `&#8203;` (zero width space) will render as `â€<`. This results in my image-snapshots looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDsBe.png

Is there any workaround here to define the character encoding?

**EDIT:** It seems I can change the container element (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container), but I can't define the container as `{ container: document.documentElement }` as apparently it needs an `.appendChild()` to work. Is it possible to define the container element as the `<html>` itself? That would solve my issue if it's possible.